# Vim plugin for python method autocomplete

Tags: python, vim, plugins

What plugins do I need to be able to get a drop down list of all methods available for a python object?

for example, say i have the following code:

```
list_object = [1,2,3]
```

I want to be able to type "list_object", hit a shortcut, and then have a selectable drop down appear that lists all
of the methods available for this object.

I have done some preliminary searching but have not been able to find anything, but I've seen screenshots of other people's vim setups and have seen such functionality in action. Also any additional resources for python specific vim development are welcomed.

Comment: To find plugins, use [vimawesome](https://vimawesome.com/), [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/) or - well - Google.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested I found the solution. The plugin YouCompleteMe does this.

Comment: My - completely subjective - feeling is that [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) has eclipsed YCM in popularity at this point.

Comment: What are some of its advantages over YouCompleteMe?

Comment: What SO (or any SE site for that matter) is notoriously bad for is open discussion (hence the downvotes). There are other sites better suited for it. This site works best with concrete questions that have one objectively correct answer. I'd encourage you to read the project descriptions and try some completion plugins yourself. It's your setup on your machine so it's really up to you to find what suits you best.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).